# How to launch IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.7.1 in OSX?

Tags: macos, cplex, opl

I have just downloaded and installed IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.7.1

In the documentation I am told to launch the IDE running

```
/.oplide
```

This does not work, since the installer did not modify my PATH. I could do it manually, but I can not find the oplide file.

Other way to launch the ide is directly running the executable file:

```
[install_dir]/opl/oplide/oplide
```

But as I said before, I cant find it in my install dir where it is supposed to be.
My instal dir is:

```
/Users/myMac/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271
```

So, the executable file should be in:

```
/Users/myMac/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/opl/oplide/oplide
```

But in the route `/Users/myMac/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/` there is no any folder called `opl`. The folders are `concert`, `cplex`, `cpoptimizer`, `doc`, `license`, `swidtag` and `Unistall`.

There is also a `README` where the launching instructions are the ones I mentioned avobe. So, what is wrong? Why I have no `opl` folder and how I am supposed to run oplide executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just found there is no studio gui for mac. Lame. If only documentation and download page would had clarified that.

Comment: The OPL IDE will be available for MacOS with CPLEX 12.8 (see the release announcement [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=AN&subtype=CA&htmlfid=897/ENUS217-343)).